# parse string SQL Server , Ruby , python?

Tags: python, sql-server, ruby, parsing

I'm trying to parse this sting of data...its an field coming from an API GET...

```
{"displayValue"=>"LNA1234", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"PNA64582", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["srp_zfeedr88N"]}
```

It looks familiar.  Like a JSON hash in ruby...

What would be the best method to parse this.  I have the data in a SQL Server table so TSQL preferable.  But I would also consider Ruby or Python if it was better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to transform and parse the stored API data as JSON.

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('{"displayValue"=>"LNA1234", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"PNA64582", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["srp_zfeedr88N"]}'),
   ('Invalid JSON data')
) v (ApiData)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.ApiData, j.*
FROM (
   SELECT 
      ApiData,
      JsonData = CASE
         WHEN ISJSON(REPLACE(ApiData, '=>', ':')) = 1 THEN REPLACE(ApiData, '=>', ':')
         ELSE NULL
      END   
   FROM Data
) t  
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(t.JsonData) j
```

Result:

| ApiData | key | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"displayValue"=>"LNA1234", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"PNA64582", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["srp_zfeedr88N"]} | displayValue | LNA1234 | 1 |
| {"displayValue"=>"LNA1234", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"PNA64582", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["srp_zfeedr88N"]} | isMulti | true | 3 |
| {"displayValue"=>"LNA1234", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"PNA64582", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["srp_zfeedr88N"]} | textValue | PNA64582 | 1 |
| {"displayValue"=>"LNA1234", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"PNA64582", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["srp_zfeedr88N"]} | type | entity_link | 1 |
| {"displayValue"=>"LNA1234", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"PNA64582", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["srp_zfeedr88N"]} | value | ["srp_zfeedr88N"] | 4 |
| Invalid JSON data |  |  |  |

Comment: I will try this...this look promising...

Comment: that works quite well...how would I pivot it back to one record easily ?

Comment: Your question just helped me find something I forgot...yes it does have a fixed structure...   My original pull of the data from the api using ruby is creating the hash that I need to parse..  Originally I didn't think I would need the individual values for that json object... so I left this one un-parsed and stored it in a sql field as is.....I need to go back and figure out the full parsing...